# Get Cpu Usage After Android 8.0 at runtime

Tags: java, android, linux

I want to get my app CPU USAGE per sec at runtime.

After Googling, access ***/proc/stat*** to get the cpu usage works before Android 8.0 , we just need some permission from the user.

However, above way can't work because Android has strict limits of authority after Android 8.0.

I just try to exec **"top command"** with shell to read cpu situation in my code.
like this :

```
public static float getProcessCpuUsageFromTopCmd(String pid){
    try{
        String[] cmd = {"sh","-c","top -n 1 "};
        //String cmd = "top -p  "+ pid;
        String line = "";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
        System.out.println(" command: "+cmd);
        //System.out.println("cpu output:"+reader.read());
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            line = line.trim();
            System.out.println("cpu output:"+line);
        }
        reader.close();
        input.close();
        process.destroy();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return 0.0f;
}
```

But the 'top' process is inside my app, it can't spy its father process which is my app.

Am I miss some permission from user? (I just want to get my own app cpu usage...)

or Any other way to get the cpu usage after Android 8.0 ?

: ) Thanks a lot to check these...

Comment: Found this at Android Developer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HardwarePropertiesManager#getCpuUsages() might help